# How can `std::error_category` safely be used in static destructors?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, std-system-error

Consider a custom error type written using the [LLVM `system_category`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/d386d7e49ace0cbfbde23f7ebec4583973daf036/src/system_error.cpp#L206-L211) implementation for reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <system_error>

struct my_error_category_type : std::error_category {
    char const* name() const  noexcept override { return "name"; }
    std::string message(int i) const noexcept override{ return "message"; }
    ~my_error_category_type() {
        std::cout << "Destroyed the category" << std::endl;
    }
};

std::error_category const& my_error_category() noexcept {
    static my_error_category_type c;
    return c;
}
```

Now imagine the following simple class that uses `std::error_code` to handle errors:

```
std::error_code do_some_setup() {
    return std::error_code(1, my_error_category());
}
std::error_code do_some_cleanup() {
    return std::error_code(2, my_error_category());
}

struct MyObj {
    void method() {
        // this constructs the category for the first time
        auto err = do_some_setup();
        std::cout << err << std::endl;
    }

    ~MyObj() {
        std::cout << "Running cleanup" << std::endl;
        auto err = do_some_cleanup();
        std::cout << err << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The following code gives alarming output

```
static MyObj obj;

int main() {
    obj.method();  // remove this line, and the output is fine
}
```

```
name:1
Destroyed the category
Running cleanup
name:2
```

Note how `my_error_category_type::message` was called on a destructed object!

My questions are:

1. Is calling `message` on this destructed object safe?
2. If not, is there a way to preserve the lifetime of the category? Can I make the object immortal somehow?
3. Does the standard make any guarantees about the lifetime of the builtin `std::system_category()` objects and the like? The LLVM implementation I link to above suffers exactly the same problem.

Comment: Looks like the answer to 1. [might be yes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30310299/102441)

Answer (score 3):

It is not safe to call object methods after its destructor is called.
The question is how to control objects order of destruction. Statics are destructed in reverse order of initialization, so my_error_category_type will be destructed before MyObj, because its constructor is called after MyObj constructor. It is not a problem, that needs to be solved by standard, but rather architectural problem.

So, we gotta somehow control the destruction order.
The simplest way is to ensure that `obj` destructor is called earlier:

```
void F() {
  MyObj obj;
  obj.method(); 
}

int main() {
  F();
}
```

Program output:

```
name:1
Running cleanup
name:2
Destroyed the category
```

Now `MyObj` destructor is called earlier, not after main, but after `F()` end, because `MyObj` is a scope variable, and it's destructed after `F()` finish and `static my_error_category_type c` is destructed when main finishes.
But if we still wanna make MyObj static, there is such technique called **Nifty Counter Idiom**, that helps to destroy statics only after last use. But it has its tradeoffs. [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter)

Similar problem with statics: "static initialization order fiasco" ([link](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order)).

Answer (score 0):

#### A static `std::error_category` can't be used safely in static destructors.

This is exactly the ["static initialization order fiasco"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) (ISO C++ Super FAQ), but at destruction, so - "static destruction order fiasco": You are not guaranteed anything, or at the very least it is difficult for you to know if and what you are guaranteed anything, about the order in which static-duration objects are destructed.

Consequently, you can't rely on this order, and specifically, the destructor of a static-storage-duration object (a global variable or a local-scope static variable) cannot assume that any other static object, such as an `std::error_category`, is not-destructed.

@DanielZ suggested circumventing the problem by making one of the variables in your example scoped - and that will obviously work. I would recommend *against* trying to manipulate or engineer the destruction order, even if that is possible, because this will result in brittle and confusing code.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a bug in the implementation of `std::system_category`.

As a work-around, `MyObj` constructor can call `std::system_category` / `my_error_category`, so that the function static error category is constructed before `MyObj` is constructed and hence destroyed only after `MyObj` is destroyed:

```
MyObj::MyObj() noexcept { static_cast<void>(my_error_category()); }
```