# How does C++ lambda wrapper around a member function works after destructor?

Tags: c++, lambda, callback

The following code work and prints out `Dead`. How does the call to `callback_fn` not cause a crash since destructor is obviously called?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

class A {
  private:
    std::string message = "Alive";
  public:
    ~A() { message = "Dead"; }
    auto get_callback() { return [this](){ callback(); }; }
  private:
    void callback() const { std::cout << message << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{   
    std::function<void()> callback_fn;
    {
        A a;
        callback_fn = a.get_callback();
    }
    callback_fn();
}
```

Since `this` is captured by value:

1. How does the member function call work after object destruction?
2. Why isn't the memory of `message` being freed at `a` destruction?

If I write `main` like this, I get no output (which I suspect to be undefined behaviour). I would expect the same behaviour as the code abve.

```
int main()
{
    auto a = std::make_unique<A>();
    auto callback_fn = a->get_callback();
    a.reset();
    callback_fn();
}
```

Comment: Related: [Is it legal to call member functions after an object has been explicitly destroyed but before its memory was deallocated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30310299/580083).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr - this code does what it does by pure accident**

You are invoking [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) here. Anything could happen when you use object after its destruction. (Un)Luckily for you it works and prints your variable. But it might as well crash the program or summon demons straight from hell as it is invalid C++ code.

Comment: Is UD invoked when calling `callback_fn` function because `this` is pointing to freed memory or when I try to print `message`?

Comment: @Garzet UB is when lambda, stored in `callback_fn`, it trying to invoke `callback()` member function for no-logner existing object. It would be UB even if `callback()` was an empty function `{ }`.